# Highlight from Amazon Cloud Reader

Tags: kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

I want to copy and paste from a book in Amazon Cloud Reader. It seems that Amazon prevents copying by default because they don't want people to commit copyright violations or something.

Anyway, I read elsewhere that the best way to do this is to create a highlight of the text, then open your highlights and copy the text from there.

However I can't manage to create a highlight. When I copy text by dragging with my cursor, nothing happens. There's no popup asking if I want to create a highlight. I think this might have been working for me on Windows (Chrome) but on Mac Chrome nothing happens. And I can't find any options in the minimalist menu.

Any ideas?